# PSexec not getting result

Tags: c#, asp.net, psexec

I am trying to create an app that connecting to other computers to delete list of users from different computers. I am using `PSexec` tool and trying to access that tool with c# by executing the command form command line. I found a code that using process and execute more than command but once I chose `PSexec.exe` as `FileName` not recognizing the command 
this is the code

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("PSexec.exe");
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\PSTools";
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
if (process != null)
{
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine("psexec \\2E01-Computer net localgroup administrators testuser/delete");
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine("ipconfig /all");
   process.StandardInput.Close(); // line added to stop process from hanging on 
   richTextBox1.Text = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

if i use `cmd.exe` to get result it work fine.

`ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe");`

by executing opconfig with cmd.exe i got this result:

```
  Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users>ipconfig 

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

  Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 14:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

but if the i chane the FileName to Psexec will not get any result as below

```
  Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\PSTools>ipconfig 

C:\PSTools>
```

and sometimes it nit returing any result.

Comment: Why don't you pass the parameters using the Arguments property of ProcessStartInfo instead of trying to write again psexec on the input stream?

Comment: it is the same result
'processStartInfo.Arguments = "ipconfig";' 
also i have two form once i make the 'filename ="psexec.exe"' it is open the other from and i have try the same code with different virsion of VS 2010/2013 both the same it is open the other form

Comment: Can you please try executing psexec from a cmd window? On my system, I cannot get the remote process output by running psexec from the command line, and this problem seems to be with psexec then. Can you please just try opening cmd and psexec \\anothermachine ipconfig

Comment: In your code also, in the StartInfo you only specify "psexec.exe" which should be the full file path if you don't have c:\pstools in your PATH environment variable. Try changing it to c:\pstools\psexec.exe

Comment: And lastly, the psexec.exe only starts with command arguments as far as I can see. I have the latest version, and when I start psexec without arguments, it displays a list of command arguments

Comment: it works fine when i run it on the command line

Comment: Ok then, can you please add process.WaitForExit() just before reading the process output and after closing the Input?

Comment: when i put the path as c:\pstools\psexec.exe it got this exception Errol The directory name is invalid

Comment: also the same with process.WaitForExit()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95875/discussion-between-oguz-ozgul-and-sam).

Comment: i am working with big network there are alot of machine connecting to the same network if i try the command psexec \\anothermachine ipconfig  or psexec \\anothermachine net localgroup administrators testuser/delete it work fine but when i am trying to execute the same command from c# it not working